# Deleting service via terminal in Grails

Tags: grails

I know I can do it manually but is there any **grails create-service** counterpart for removing a service?

Comment: how would such a command line method figure out the usages of the created service and if it would really be safe to remove the file without then ending up breaking the end application? This sort of thing is best left for your IDE. For example in Intellij if you were to ask it to remove a service it would try to calculate where it is used and provide you with an overview of what was about to happen.

Comment: Incidentally you ever tried touching (Creating) a file in a service folder. Try this create a folder called test inside it put TestService.groovy inside TestService,groovy `class TestService { def doSomething() { return "hello"} } ` Now call it from  a controller - so in theory you could make your own shell script to generate a service and remove the file - ultimately it is a file with a certain naming Convention `SomenameService.groovy` and Controller is `SomenameController.groovy` in controllers folder - Grails takes care of the rest - hope it helps you overcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is not.  As others have said, removal is more dangerous than creation.  Either use an IDE, or remove the service manually after checking for any usages.